# Performance Optimization of query using XML.Modify() in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, performance, sql-server-2008

I am generating an XML using FOR XML in SQL Server 2008.

The XML output generated is of 5.18 MB and the process up to generation of XML takes just 5 seconds.

Now, I am adding attributes in this XML using XML.modify. After modification the size increases to 5.25 MB. But the file takes 17 minutes for this remaining processing (adding the attributes).

I am keeping the XML data in an XML type variable,there are around 6000 rows in this XML document and i am adding the attributes in approx half of the rows. These attributes are added under different node with some condition. The maximum time in 17 minutes approx(16 minutes) are consumed while adding these attributes.

I would request, if some one can tell me the best practices and  ways to improving the performance.

**XML Generated before adding the Styles**

```
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
        <Workbook xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
          <Worksheet xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ss:Name="INDEX">
            <Table xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
              <Column></Column>
              <Row xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
                <Cell xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
                  <Data ss:Type="String">#</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
                  <Data ss:Type="String">Study Name</Data>
                </Cell>
```

**XML after adding attributes**

```
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
        <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
          <Styles xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">

          <Worksheet xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ss:Name="INDEX">
            <Table xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ss:DefaultRowHeight="50">
              <Row xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ss:StyleID="s66">
                <Cell xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ss:MergeAcross="5">
                  <Data ss:Type="String">#</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
                  <Data ss:Type="String">Study Name</Data>
                </Cell>
```

**Code to generate Basic XML**

```
CREATE TABLE TempData (
    [ID] [INT] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,[Col1] [NVARCHAR](MAX)
    ,[Col2] [NVARCHAR](MAX)
    ,[Col3] [NVARCHAR](MAX)
    ,[WORKSHEET_ID] INT 
    ,[FORM_OID] [NVARCHAR](MAX)
    ,[Col4] [NVARCHAR](MAX)
    ,[Col5] [NVARCHAR](MAX)
    ,[Col6] [NVARCHAR](MAX)
    ,[Col7] [NVARCHAR](MAX)
    ,[Col8] [NVARCHAR](MAX)
    ,[Col9] [NVARCHAR](MAX)
    ,[RANKING] INT
    );

SELECT  @xml = (SELECT (
          SELECT  
            CASE WHEN a2.[FORM_OID]='INDEX' THEN a2.[FORM_OID]
            ELSE  SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(10),(a2.[WORKSHEET_ID]-1))+'_'+ a2.[FORM_OID],0,31) 
            END  '@ss:Name',(
                  SELECT '' as [Column],(
                           SELECT   
                               (SELECT 
                                      'String' as [Data/@ss:Type],
                                      [Col1] as [Data]
                                      FOR XML PATH('Cell'), TYPE),
                                      (SELECT 
                                     'String' as [Data/@ss:Type],
                                      [Col2] as [Data]  
                                      FOR XML PATH('Cell'), TYPE),
                                      (SELECT 
                                     'String' as [Data/@ss:Type],
                                      [Col3] as [Data]  
                                      FOR XML PATH('Cell'), TYPE),
                                      (SELECT 
                                     'String' as [Data/@ss:Type],
                                      [Col4] as [Data]  
                                      FOR XML PATH('Cell'), TYPE),
                                      (SELECT 
                                     'String' as [Data/@ss:Type],
                                      [Col5] as [Data]  
                                      FOR XML PATH('Cell'), TYPE),
                                      (SELECT 
                                     'String' as [Data/@ss:Type],
                                      [Col6] as [Data]  
                                      FOR XML PATH('Cell'), TYPE),
                                      (SELECT 
                                     'String' as [Data/@ss:Type],
                                      [Col7] as [Data]  
                                      FOR XML PATH('Cell'), TYPE),
                                      (SELECT 
                                     'String' as [Data/@ss:Type],
                                      [Col8] as [Data]  
                                      FOR XML PATH('Cell'), TYPE),
                                      (SELECT 
                                     'String' as [Data/@ss:Type],
                                      [Col9] as [Data]  
                                      FOR XML PATH('Cell'), TYPE),
                                      (SELECT 
                                     'String' as [Data/@ss:Type],
                                      [RANKING] as [Data]  
                                      FOR XML PATH('Cell'), TYPE)
                               FROM TempData  a1
                               WHERE a1.[WORKSHEET_ID]=a2.[WORKSHEET_ID]
                               GROUP BY [ID],[Col1],[Col2],[Col3],[FORM_OID],[Col4],[Col5],[Col6],[Col7],[Col8],[Col9],[RANKING] --form oid
                               order by [ID]
                         FOR XML PATH('Row'), TYPE
                         )
                  FOR XML PATH('Table'), TYPE
                         )
           FROM TempData  a2
           group by [WORKSHEET_ID],[FORM_OID]
    FOR XML PATH('Worksheet'), TYPE)          
    FOR XML PATH('Workbook'), TYPE )
```

**Code to add Style** (One of the many attributes i am adding)

```
SET @xml.modify('declare default element namespace  "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet";
                    declare namespace ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ;
                    declare namespace x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel";
                    insert  attribute ss:MergeAcross{"5"}           
                    into (/Workbook/Worksheet[position()=sql:variable("@worksheets")][1]/Table/Row[1]/Cell[1])[1]')
```

Comment: Is there a chance to add these attributes while generating the XML? If not it might be much faster to read the whole thing and re-generate it. Please show an (reduced!) example of your XML and the SQL you're using

Comment: Its not possible to add these attributes while generating the skeleton XML. Here is alink to the sample file format i am generating https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats#Excel_XML_Spreadsheet_example.

Comment: So you are trying to create an MS-Office-Document as XML. Which attributes are there to be inserted later?

Comment: @Shnugo Yes, I am build MS-Office-Excel as XML. I am adding the Styles and attributes after data is generated.These attributes are  to color the headers and coloring the some rows on behalf of data that is populated.

Comment: something is wrong with your query, pleas show it with table/tables structures. Also you can insert data to temporary table and then convert to xml, if only 6000 rows insert should be quick and query simpler to analyze

Comment: @PiotrLasota I am inserting the data to a Temporary table. Then generating the XML from that table and then adding styles and statements to the generated XML so that it can be opened in Excel. But adding attributes to the XML is talking most time.

Comment: The `.modify()` allows only one modification per call. That means you have to call this approx. 3000 times. This is RBAR at its best... There are two approaches I'd think about: Shred the whole XML into table-like data and rebuild it with your attributes, or place placeholders from the beginning and use string methods (`STUFF`, `REPLACE`) to get your attributes into the XML. I'd prefer the first...

Comment: Your last comment let's me come to one more suggestion: Keep the temporary table from which you've created the first XML. In the second step re-create the whole XML together with the attributes. Repeated `.modify()` is - for sure! - the slowest possible solution...

Comment: @NimbleFungus so show the query :) and example of what xml structure you want

Comment: @Shnugo It will be really really complex to build the XML with attributes from the same table again. But i will give it a try . 
What do u suggest about using XML indexing on the XML skeleton i created and keep doing the same thing again? I want to avoid disturb the whole code but will do if things do not improve.

Comment: XML indexing is - in most cases no big help and it will not speed up several thousand RBAR modify calls... Show your SQL code!

Comment: @PiotrLasota It's a huge code butthe xml that i am trying to generate is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats#Excel_XML_Spreadsheet_example.

Comment: Well, maybe *huge code* is to much to post it in total, but you could try to reduce it to a typical section with the attributes you want to fill in later. So: Show a tiny SQL to create a tiny section, then show the XML as it comes out and the XML with the attributes as it should look after your modfications...

Comment: If it is so complicated then maybe you should try other way to do it, by Excel, Vba and sql. Prepare macro in vba to get value from database (simple select, not xml) and add styles and whatever in vba. Also you can automate it by sql jobs

Comment: Guys i have added the sample values and queries in question. I am not sure how much helpful they are. Please have a look. I am really thankful for you help.
@PiotrLasota I have a environmental limitation. i have to use SQL for this.

Comment: Now this is a full and complete question. Worth an upvote!

Comment: @Shnugo Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any update in suggestion, after seeing the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This modified query will at least reduce the number of bytes drastically by avoiding so many repeated namespace declarations. If you cannot go with my suggestion (read below), this should speed up things anyway. 3000 RBAR modify calls should be faster with about 10% of the size...

I hope you can use this for your full query:

```
CREATE TABLE TempData (
    [ID] [INT] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,[Col1] [NVARCHAR](MAX)
    ,[Col2] [NVARCHAR](MAX)
    ,[Col3] [NVARCHAR](MAX)
    ,[WORKSHEET_ID] INT 
    ,[FORM_OID] [NVARCHAR](MAX)
    ,[Col4] [NVARCHAR](MAX)
    ,[Col5] [NVARCHAR](MAX)
    ,[Col6] [NVARCHAR](MAX)
    ,[Col7] [NVARCHAR](MAX)
    ,[Col8] [NVARCHAR](MAX)
    ,[Col9] [NVARCHAR](MAX)
    ,[RANKING] INT
    );
INSERT INTO TempData(Col1,Col2,Col3,WORKSHEET_ID,FORM_OID,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,RANKING) 
VALUES('test1','test2','test3',1,'formOID','test4','test5','test6','test7','test8','test9',100);

DECLARE @xml XML;
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet' AS ss
                  ,'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel' AS x
                  ,DEFAULT 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet')
SELECT  @xml = 
(
    SELECT  
        CASE WHEN a2.[FORM_OID]='INDEX' THEN a2.[FORM_OID]
        ELSE  SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(10),(a2.[WORKSHEET_ID]-1))+'_'+ a2.[FORM_OID],0,31) 
        END  '@ss:Name',
        (
            SELECT '' as [Column],
            (
                SELECT   
                    'String' as [Cell/Data/@ss:Type],
                    [Col1] as [Cell/Data],
                    '',
                    'String' as [Cell/Data/@ss:Type],
                    [Col2] as [Cell/Data],
                    '',
                    'String' as [Cell/Data/@ss:Type],
                    [Col3] as [Cell/Data],
                    '',
                    5 AS [Cell/@ss:MergeAcross],       --Read below!
                    'String' as [Cell/Data/@ss:Type],
                    [Col4] as [Cell/Data],
                    '',
                    'String' as [Cell/Data/@ss:Type],
                    [Col5] as [Cell/Data],
                    '',
                    'String' as [Cell/Data/@ss:Type],
                    [Col7] as [Cell/Data],
                    '',
                    'String' as [Cell/Data/@ss:Type],
                    [Col8] as [Cell/Data],
                    '',
                    'String' as [Cell/Data/@ss:Type],
                    [Col9] as [Cell/Data],
                    '',
                    'String' as [Cell/Data/@ss:Type],
                    [RANKING] as [Cell/Data]

                    FROM TempData  a1
                    WHERE a1.[WORKSHEET_ID]=a2.[WORKSHEET_ID]
                    GROUP BY [ID],[Col1],[Col2],[Col3],[FORM_OID],[Col4],[Col5],[Col6],[Col7],[Col8],[Col9],[RANKING] --form oid
                    order by [ID]
                FOR XML PATH('Row'), TYPE
            ) 
            FOR XML PATH('Table'), TYPE
        )
    FROM TempData  a2
    group by [WORKSHEET_ID],[FORM_OID]
    FOR XML PATH('Worksheet'), ROOT('Workbook')
);

SELECT @xml;

--CleanUp
--DROP TABLE TempData;
```

If you look closely to the "Col4" you'll see, that I introduced the MergeAcross-Attribut directly in the call. What do you think about adding more columns to your temp table or define a second temptable for styles if they are 1:n and add them "on the fly"?

Comment: That's really great..!! I will update the code and will get back to you after  bench-marking.  I will try to as much as possible attributes in the main query.
Thanks a lot.  :)

Comment: Atleast one update is there. The above changes have reduced the size of XML to half.  I am still changing the XML to use the attributes. will update u soon.

Comment: Great! Go on killing bytes! I must admit I had expected a reduction of at least 70%... There were tons of repeated name space declarations. But the content of your tables will be more than the example shows...

Comment: Thanks a lot. your idea worked. The query is now completing in less than 1 minute. I am adding the most of the attributes when query is generating the basic XML as suggested by you.

Comment: Can you please tell what is the use of '' in the below text. This test is part of the query u provided.
<PRE> <code> \* SELECT   
                    'String' as [Cell/Data/@ss:Type],
                    [Col1] as [Cell/Data],
                    '', */

Comment: Can yopu please tell me what is '' in the Select statement for Col1. 
Below is the sample code from above code u provided.
SELECT   
                    'String' as [Cell/Data/@ss:Type],
                    [Col1] as [Cell/Data],
                    '',

Comment: @NimbleFungus It is needed to get identically named Elements with attributes. Without you'll get a Syntax error

Comment: Shnugo i have a question in this same context . How can i put condition aroud  [Col1] as [Cell/Data]. So that i can generate  [Col1] as [Cell/ss:Data], (see ss:data) in case col1='Italics' . I am ubale to generate this correctly.

Comment: @NimbleFungus Hi, please place a new question and poste a link to this here. I'll pop up there soon. In general: New questions pull the most attention...

Comment: Thanks for response. i have added the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40048091/unable-to-add-condition-in-for-xml-part