# Unable to add condition in FOR XML part

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, for-xml-path

I have generated a FOR XML with the help from this
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36700950/performance-optimization-of-query-using-xml-modify-in-sql-server-2008/36704005?noredirect=1#comment67371594_36704005). 
In the solution there is a condition

```
SELECT   
                    'String' as [Cell/Data/@ss:Type],
                    [Col1] as [Cell/Data],
                    '',
                    'String' as [Cell/Data/@ss:Type],
                    [Col2] as [Cell/Data],
                    '',
```

I want to add a condition to this part 
which says

```
SELECT      
                CASE 
                    WHEN COL1 LIKE '%SUP%'
                    THEN
                    'String' as [Cell/ss:Data/@ss:Type]
                    ELSE 
                    'String' as [Cell/Data/@ss:Type]
                    END ,
                [Col1] as [Cell/Data],
                '',
```

But i am getting issues. 
Kindly help me with this.

This basic code above showing the Syntax  error.
 If i add

```
SELECT      
                    CASE 
                        WHEN COL1 LIKE '%SUP%'
                        THEN
                        (SELECT 'String' as [Cell/ss:Data/@ss:Type])
                        ELSE 
                        (SELECT 'String' as [Cell/Data/@ss:Type])
                        END ,
                    [Col1] as [Cell/Data],
                    '','
```

Then the generated XML is not correct

Comment: What would those issues be?

Comment: @AndrewMorton i have added the issue in question

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're saying, then if `Col1` contains the string "SUP", you want this tag in your final XML:

```
<ss:Data ss:Type="String">SomethingContainingSup</ss:Data>
```

Otherwise, you want this expression:

```
<Data ss:Type="String">SomethingElse</Data>
```

I think you can get that with this SQL fragment:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COL1 LIKE '%SUP%' THEN 'String' END  as [Cell/ss:Data/@ss:Type],
       CASE WHEN Col1 Like '%SUP%' THEN Col1 END as [Cell/ss:Data], 
       CASE WHEN COL1 NOT LIKE '%SUP%' THEN 'String' END  as [Cell/Data/@ss:Type],                    
       CASE WHEN Col1 NOT Like '%SUP%' THEN Col1  END as [Cell/Data],
       ''
```

Why yours didn't work:  you can't make the name of a column (or of an XML element) conditional.  The closest you can get is to make one or the other expression evaluate to null, in which case it won't be rendered in the final XML.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Let me try your idea.

Comment: im sorry I will try this in a day or two. Im stuck with some other task . Thanks for asking. Sorry :(